# "generic object" data type in solidity

Tags: solidity, struct, data-types

Is there a data type similar to "object" in C# that any solidity data type could rely on?
I currently have a struct with multiple fields and I would need one of them to be either a string, a boolean,... depending on the situation. Is there a "clean" way to do that?

Comment: No, currently there's no such type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, unfortunately there is not such a type in solidity....